# Command 'rvm' not found, did you mean:

Tags: ruby, rvm

I just installed rvm on my kali machine but after rebooting it, the terminal said that the command wasn't found and asked if I meant something else. I used `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` to install and run the rvm install script. Everything went smooth and when the script finished, it said that all I had to do to get rvm running was execute `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`, which I did. I even checked my path to make sure that everything was normal, and I think it is. Here is what it is:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin:/opt/impacket/build/scripts-3.9:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/go/bin/:/root/go-workspace/bin
```

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: Did you add `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` to your bashrc (or the equivalent for your shell)?

Comment: @iCodeSometime, thank you. That was the solution. If you post your comment as an answer, I could accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to update your bashrc (or equivalent) so that the rvm stuff gets imported every time.

Just add `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` to the end of that file